# converting an array of objects to a different structure of array of objects

Tags: javascript, dataset

how do i turn this dataset

```
file = 
[ 
{ 
DeviceName: 'DeviceName1',
counter1: '85%',
counter2: '87%',
counter3: '75%',
counter4: '63%' },
{ 
DeviceName: 'DeviceName2',
counter1: '85%',
counter2: '87%',
counter3: '75%',
counter4: '63%' 
} 
]
```

into this

```
data = [
      {
        key: "Device1",
        color: "#51A351",
        values:
          [      
            { x : "counter1", y : '85%' },
            { x : "counter2", y : '87%' },
            { x : "counter3", y : '75%' },
            { x : "counter4", y : '63%' }
          ]
      },
      {
        key: "Device2",
        color: "#BD362F",
        values:
          [      
            { x : "counter1", y : '85%' },
            { x : "counter2", y : '87%' },
            { x : "counter3", y : '75%' },
            { x : "counter4", y : '63%' }
          ]
      }
    ];
```

this is my attempt

```
file.map(function(d,i){return {key:d.DeviceName,color:i}})
```

but this only gets me this far:

```
[ { key: 'DeviceName1', color: 0 },
  { key: 'DeviceName2', color: 1 } ]
```

Comment: And where does the color come from ?

Comment: What's the logic connecting a single element of `file` with a single element of `data`? Nothing here is very clear: where did the `color` attribute come from in `data`? What's the relationship between `DeviceName` in `file` elements and `key` in `data`? (Just edit out the `"Name"` substring?) Are you always expecting exactly four `counter*` properties in `file` elements?

Comment: its for building a graph, so there would need to be a different color for each device. I was hoping to have another array for the colors.Was hoping to make it as dynamic as possible, so want it to handle N counters and these could all have dynmamic names also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first define where the colors came from. Then you can loop/reduce properties of your object (using Object.keys()) to construct `values` array:

```
var colors = ["#51A351", "#BD362F"];

var result = file.map(function(item, i) {
    var values = Object.keys(item).reduce(function(r, key) {
        return key == 'DeviceName' ? r : r.concat({ x: key, y: item[key] });
    }, []);
    return {
        values: values,
        key: item.DeviceName,
        color: colors[i]
    };
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: tks think that looks the part, let me just digest it.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
file.map(function(d,i){
return {
key:d.DeviceName,
color:d.color,
values: [{
x: 'counter1', y: d.counter1
},{
x: 'counter2', y: d.counter2
},{
x: 'counter3', y: d.counter3
},{
x: 'counter4', y: d.counter4
}]}
})
```

Comment: Except `d.color` will be `undefined`, since there is no `color` attribute anywhere in the original data.

Comment: Indeed. But as there is no `color` in the original data, we can't really map it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This solution moves the `counter1`, ... to the right place of the array with regular expression for the index of the array.

```js
var file = [{ DeviceName: 'DeviceName1', counter2: '87%', counter1: '85%', counter3: '75%', counter4: '63%' }, { DeviceName: 'DeviceName2', counter1: '85%', counter2: '87%', counter3: '75%', counter4: '63%' }],
    data = file.map(function (a, i) {
        var o = {
            key: a.DeviceName.split('Name').join(''),
            color: ['#51A351', '#BD362F'][i],
            values: []
        };
        Object.keys(a).filter(function (b) {
            return /^counter\d+$/.test(b);
        }).forEach(function (c) {
            o.values[c.match(/\d+/) - 1] = { x: c, y: a[c] };
        })
        return o;
    });
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(data, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```